# Sitecore pdf file enable .pdf extension

Tags: media-library

For some reason the PDF files (that are uploaded on media library) are shown as *.ashx when referencing from RTE etc.

Is there a way to show *.pdf instead so that it's user/seo friendly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change bellow setting from ashx to empty string.

```
<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value="ashx" />
```

will be

```
<setting name="Media.RequestExtension" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, we would like to show the actual media name instead of guid. myfile.pdf instead of 121212121211.ashx.

Comment: do you have guid on frontend or just when you open RTE ?

Comment: Front end after page is rendered

Comment: @NilPun please open another question for this - it is extra to the first question which has been answered. Thanks